# python's super - how can I choose which implementation to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

my question is given this dummy code:

```
class A:
    def display(self): print("FOO")

class B(A):
    def display(self): print("BAZ")

class C(B):
    def display(self): super().display() # I want it to call A.display and not B's

C().display()
```

how can I make C's display to print A's message and not B's (I actually want to skip B's dispaly completely)?

Comment: I think, this has already been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance

Comment: While your could always do a `A.display(self)` it is considered bad practice. You should take a moment to re-think your order of inheritance.